# Laravel blade form closing issue

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have a form in Laravel like this:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
          {!! Form::model($questionGroup, ['route' => ['question_groups.update', $questionGroup->id, 'model_slug' => 'assessments', 'model_id' => $assessment->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}
          <p>TEST</p>
          {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

This outputs the following in my source:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/admin/question_groups/7?model_slug=assessments&amp;model_id=1" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
   <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
   <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="E6HzCmQvRGds6eETgdCv5KCsf0eyOtjxvqnidrTx">
   <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

I have no idea why the form is not closing properly. Any ideas? I'm using Laravel 5.5 and this form is in a Bootstrap Modal.

**EDIT:**

Here is a link to the full html: https://gist.github.com/shabaz-ejaz/96be7b4b20ba9146436f1f9f1d274211

The file is quite big so search for `question_groups.update` and that is where the form begins.

Comment: Try replacing `{!! !!}` with `{{ }}`

Comment: Tried it. Same thing happens.

Comment: can you check your html ? is there any other open <form> tag ?

Comment: There are <form> tags but they are all closed correctly. I have included the full view html code in my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was related to non well-formed HTML.

My modal was inside a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>

        <form ...>

        </form>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Once I placed the `<form>` inside the `<td>` it worked fine.

Comment: I'd just made this exact mistake.  Thank you for this post.